# How to change quotes expiration date on Magento B2B?

Tags: magento2, quote, b2b, cloud

My clients are able to quote items within a period of 30 days. I can see the expiration date on the screen below.

[image: Adobe Commerce B2B Quotes expiration date]

How could I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it by accessing **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Quotes > General > Default Expiration Period**, as you can see in the image below, you'll find an option for it.

[image: Adobe Commerce B2B expiration date to quotes]